# R, calculating various levels of ecdf() for list elements

Tags: r, loops, ecdf

I have a list [list] of several elements, [elem] say 10, each of which contains random values, say 100, in column [values]. I would like to create a table that contains outputs of cumulative distribution, ecdf() function, at various levels of probability, say in a sequence ranging from 0.5 to 1 in steps of 0.05. I can do it for each [elem] of the list at a single level of probability (0.9 used below) but am unable to create a nested loop to run the various steps in the sequence. Any help much appreciated including any better approaches than nested loops.

```
prob <- 0.9

for (i in 1:elem) {
  ecdf.calc <- ecdf(list[[i]]$values)
  list[[i]] <- ecdf.calc(prob)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, why not simply `prob <- seq(0.5, 1, 0.05)` followed by your code?

Comment: That solves the problem, thank you!